# Sonar Server 5.6 is broken after Java upgrade

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

I have Sonar server 5.6, it was working fine with Java 1.8. I upgraded Java to 1.9, I updated wrapper.conf file to use 1.8 JDK

wrapper.java.command=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin

wrapper.java.command=java

When I run StartSonar.bat file I get following error

> --> Wrapper Started as Console Launching a JVM... Wrapper (Version 3.2.3) http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.org   Copyright 1999-2006 Tanuki Software, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
>
> 2018.01.10 17:02:23 INFO  app[o.s.a.AppFileSystem] Cleaning or creating temp directory C:\sonar\sonarqube-5.6\temp Error occurred
>   during initialization of VM agent library failed to init: instrument
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option UseParNewGC was
>   deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be removed in a future
>   release. Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Option
>   UseConcMarkSweepGC was deprecated in version 9.0 and will likely be
>   removed in a future release. Error opening zip file or JAR manifest
>   missing : **C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1\lib\management-agent.jar**
>   2018.01.10 17:02:23 INFO  app[o.s.p.m.JavaProcessLauncher] Launch process[es]: **C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1\bin\java**
>   -Djava.awt.headless=true -Xmx1G -Xms256m -Xss256k -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -XX:+UseParNewGC -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75 -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -Djava.io.tmpdir=C:\sonar\sonarqube-5.6\temp -javaagent:**C:\Program Files\Java\jre-9.0.1\lib\management-agent.jar** -cp
>   ./lib/common/*;./lib/search/* org.sonar.search.SearchServer
>   C:\sonar\sonarqube-5.6\temp\sq-process5945663641444744932properties
>   <-- Wrapper Stopped

From the log it appears that it is still using Java 1.9. Can anybody please tell me how to resolve it ?

Atul

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java 9's not supported as a runtime even for the current LTS, 6.7, much less the previous LTS, 5.6, which was released before Java 9 was even available.

To resolve this, downgrade your version of Java.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I understand officially it is not supported, I was playing with the params - changed the parameters in wrapper.conf then even Java 9 worked for me  wrapper.java.command=C:/Program Files/Java/jre-9.0.1/bin/java       <- Uncomment this line & add "Java"
#wrapper.java.command=java   <- Comment this line